# how to use wrtc to send UDP packet to TURN server?

Tags: node.js, udp, webrtc, stun, turn

I am thinking about how to send UDP packet to TURN server. I would like to use WebRTC and WRTC is the node implementation of it. However after some research I am still not sure.

Another question is what is the returned response looks like from webRTC? if the connection success, will it return some signal to let us know that it is working?

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC library expects STUN and TURN server details (i.e. ICE servers) as an input during the initialization of the RTCPeerConnection object. During the connection negotiation (i.e. ICE negotiataion), WebRTC library on both ends tries to find the best ICE candidate to use. If you only configure TURN server and not provide STUN server WebRTC should do data transfer through a TURN server.

PeerConnection object gives a variety of connection states as a part of connection state change callback (i.e. oniceconnectionstatechange). You can look for a CONNECTED state.

```
// List of ICE servers
iceServerList = {'iceServers':[{'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};

pcConfig = iceServerList || {"iceServers": [] };
pcOptions = { "optional": [{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true} ] };

// Pass ICE servers here
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pcConfig, pcOptions);

...
...

// ICE connection state listener
pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = function(evt) {
        var videoElement = document.getElementById(streamer.videoElement);
        if (videoElement) {
                if (pc.iceConnectionState === "connected") {
                        console.log("Connected")
                }
                else if (pc.iceConnectionState === "disconnected") {
                        console.log("Disconnected")
                }
                else if ( (pc.iceConnectionState === "failed") || (pc.iceConnectionState === "closed") )  {
                        console.log("Error")
                }
        }
}
```